# Append list to existing csv according the header

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I Have CSV with header

> KlM1,KLM2,KLM3

and i have List

```
['1', 'Tafsir An-Nas (114) Aya 6', '4-6. Aku berlindung kepada-Nya dari kejahatan bisikan setan yang bersembunyi pada diri manusia dan selalu bersamanya layaknya darah yang mengalir di dalam tubuhnya, yang membisikkan kejahatan dan kesesatan ke dalam dada manusia dengan cara yang halus, lihai, licik, dan menjanjikan secara terus-menerus. Aku berlindung kepada-Nya dari setan pembisik kejahatan dan kesesatan yang berasal dari golongan jin, yakni makhluk halus yang tercipta dari api, dan juga dari golongan manusia yang telah menjadi budak setan.']
```

but when I save with this code:

```
list1 = ['1',''+str(test)+'',''+arti2+''] 
with open('Alquran.csv', 'a') as file:
    coba=csv.writer(file)
    coba.writerows(list1)
```

they just fill in KLM1 
how can i save the list like as a header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide *all* rows to `writerows(...)` - it takes a *list of rows* and each row is a *list of columns:*:

```
import csv

header = ["h1","h2","h3"]
row1 = [11,12,13]
row2 = [21,22,23]

# always use newline="" for csv-module opened file
with open('Alquran.csv', 'a', newline="") as file:
    coba=csv.writer(file)
    # list of rows, each row is a list of columns 
    coba.writerows( [header, row1, row2] )

with open('Alquran.csv',"r") as r:
    print(r.read())
```

Output:

```
h1,h2,h3
11,12,13
21,22,23
```

To later add more information:

```
another_row = [31,32,33]

with open('Alquran.csv', 'a', newline="") as file:
    coba=csv.writer(file)
    # list of 1 row, containing 3 columns 
    coba.writerows( [another_row] )

with open('Alquran.csv',"r") as r:
    print(r.read())
```

Output after adding:

```
h1,h2,h3
11,12,13
21,22,23
31,32,33
```

---

Doku:

- [csv.writerows(..)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows)
- for seperate row-writing, read [Difference between writerow() and writerows() methods of Python csv module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091980/difference-between-writerow-and-writerows-methods-of-python-csv-module)