# Upload a CSV directly to AWS S3 without saving to disk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, pycharm

> I scraped a website, created a PySpark DataFrame and now I would like to
>   upload the DataFrame in a CSV format to my AWS S3 bucket without
>   saving to disk.

*I use PyCharm IDE (where I set my Access Key and Secret Access Key and selected the region. The program is written in Python.*

**I created the DataFrame like this:**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf, schema=mySchema)
```

Thus, it is not yet a CSV file, because if I create a CSV that gets saved to disk.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031463/can-you-upload-to-s3-using-a-stream-rather-than-a-local-file
Take a look at this

Comment: Terrific, thanks it solved the issue! It's a possible duplicate, will make sure to delete the question.