# File streaming in python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, flask, stream, boto3

I am working on Python flask REST Api to upload files to S3/ECS. My code is working perfectly fine and uploading files to S3/ECS. Here is the code...

```
def UploadFileToEcs(self,inputData,file):
        BucketName = inputData.ecsbucketname
        newpath = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir() , inputData.filename)
        file.save(newpath)

        s3_client = boto3.client('s3',endpoint_url=inputData.endpointUrl, 
                                 aws_access_key_id=inputData.access_key_id,
                                 aws_secret_access_key=inputData.secret_key)

        try:
            newkey = inputData.folderpath + '/' + inputData.filename
            response = s3_client.upload_file(newpath, BucketName,newkey)
        except Exception as e:
            return "error while uploading files to ECS" + str(e)
        return True
```

The problem comes when the file size is too large like 8-10GB.

I am using PCF cloud and my container cannot go beyond 2GB RAM size. So my service fails in this scenario and give me error like...

```
Disk Quota exceed or No space available.
```

This is how I am receiving file on my rest api and calling ecsConnection to upload the file...

```
 def UploadFileToEcs(self,request):
        try:
            inputData = self.getInputDataFromRequest(request)
            if(inputData == None):
                print('unable to retrieve request data. Terminating the request.')
                raise BadRequest("unable to retrieve request data. Terminating the request.")

            print('provided input is:= ' + inputData.getString())
            file = request.files['file']
            connector = EcsConnector()
            isSuccessful = connector.UploadFileToEcs(inputData,file)
            return str(isSuccessful)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            return str(e)
```

The question is: how can I call the service to accept file as stream and call S3 api to upload the stream. I believe with this approach I can reduce the memory footprint and upload even bigger size of file.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031463/can-you-upload-to-s3-using-a-stream-rather-than-a-local-file

Comment: Thanks.. it is what I needed...