# Python boto3 multipart upload video to aws s3

Tags: python, opencv, amazon-s3, file-upload, boto3

I want to upload a video in multiparts, I have a function that reads a video do some processing on the frame and now instead of writing it to local disk i want to send it to aws s3.
I have figured out way to upload in parts using boto3 client

```
import cv2
import boto3


multipart_upload = MultipartUpload(<AWS_BUCKET_NAME>, <AWS_KEY>)
multipart_upload.open()
video_path = "video.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
ok = cap.isOpened()
while ok:
    ok,frame = cap.read()

    # do some processing on the frame

    """ then some code to convert these frames into video file writable bytes and collect bytes upto 5MB (specified in aws docs and pass to upload method)"""

    byte_data = frames_to_video_files(frame)  # i am not able to figure out how this part will work

    multipart_upload.upload(byte_data)

multipart_upload.close()


class MultipartUpload:

   def __init__(self,bucket,key):
       self.bucket = bucket
       self.key = key
       self.s3 = boto3.client("s3")
       self.parts = []

   def open(self):
       response = s3.create_multipart_upload(ACL="public-read",Bucket=self.bucket,ContentType="video/mp4",Key=self.key)
       self.upload_id = response["UploadId"]

   def upload(self,bytes_data,part_number):
       response = self.s3.upload_part(Bucket=self.bucket,Key=self.key,Body=bytes_data,PartNumber=part_number,UploadId=self.upload_id)
       self.parts.append({"ETag":response["ETag"],"PartNumber":part_number})

   def close(self):
       response = self.s3.complete_multipart_upload(Bucket=self.bucket,Key=self.key,UploadId=self.upload_id,MultipartUpload={"Parts":self.parts})
       print(response)
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Boto3 manages multipart and non-multipart transfers [by default](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3.html#file-transfer-configuration).

Comment: Yes that's true. But it's helpful when I have a complete file on my disk, my use case is I have streams of data (video frames) that I want to upload as a video file

Comment: I understood your problem statement, I think you can achieve solution using this. 
Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31054669/1075358