# Lambda S3 Memory Error trying to write CSV to S3

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a list of dictionaries that represents a CSV file, and I would like to write them to S3, however I am getting a memory error. Here Id my code:

```
import csv
import io

dicts = [] # populated with about 1,000,000 dictionaries representing a CSV
f = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=dicts[0].keys())
writer.writeheader()
            
for k in dicts:
    writer.writerow(k)
            
print("Writing to S3...")
response = s3.upload_fileobj(Bucket='mybucket', Key=f"key.csv", Fileobj=f.getvalue())
f.close()
```

However, when I run this I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] MemoryErrorTraceback (most recent call last):  
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 85, in lambda_handler
response = s3.upload_fileobj(Bucket='mybucket', Key=f"key.csv", Fileobj=f.getvalue())
```

How can I go about writing this to S3 in a more memory efficient way? the CSV is about 400mb and has around 1,000,000 rows.

EDIT:

I have the max amount of memory available, here is the report from lambda:

```
REPORT RequestId: c8f651cf-9869-4217-921f-52edcf577234  
Duration: 123484.03 ms  
Billed Duration: 123485 ms  
Memory Size: 10240 MB   
Max Memory Used: 10043 MB   
Init Duration: 453.23 ms
```

I have run a memory profiler and the vast majority of the memory is used writing to `f` and `f.getvalue()` unsurprisingly

EDIT:

Here is the full lambda function code:

```
for i in event['files']:
    try:
        file = s3.get_object(Bucket="incomingbucket", Key=i)
        print(file)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, i)

    file_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    jsonRootLs = i.split(".")
    if len(jsonRootLs) > 1:
        jsonRoot = '.'.join(j for j in jsonRootLs[0:len(jsonRootLs)-1])
        jsonFileName = f"{jsonRoot}.json"
    else:
        jsonRoot = jsonRootLs[0]
        jsonFileName = f"{jsonRoot}.json"
        
    mapper = s3.get_object(Key=jsonFileName, Bucket='slm-addressfile-incoming')
    mapperJSON = json.loads(mapper['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))

    dicts = modelerFile(file, mapperJSON)
    for j in dicts:
        j['mail_filename'] = i
        j['file_id'] = file_id
    dictsToSend.extend(dicts)
    print("Records added to list")
        
    f = io.StringIO()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=dicts[0].keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    
    for k in dicts:
        writer.writerow(k)
    
    print("Writing to S3...")
    response = s3.upload_fileobj(Bucket='slm-test-bucket-transactional', Key=f"{jsonRoot}.csv", Fileobj=f.getvalue())
    f.close()

# Function to re map columns
def customFile(file, mapperjson):
    NCOAFields = mapperjson['mappings']
    lines1 = []
    for line in file['Body'].iter_lines():
        lines1.append(line.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore'))

    fieldnames = lines1[0].replace('"','').split(',')
    jlist1 = (dict(row) for row in csv.DictReader(lines1[1:], fieldnames))
    
    dicts = []
    for i in jlist1:
        d = {}
        metadata = {}
        for k, v in i.items():
            if k in NCOAFields:
                d[NCOAFields[k]] = v
            else:
                metadata[k] = v
        if len(metadata) > 0:
            d['metadata'] = metadata
        d['individual_id'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
        dicts.append(d)
        
    del jlist1

    return dicts
```

Basically it reads a CSV rom S3 which also has a JSON mapping file to change names of the columns to our destination schema

Comment: What are the memory settings on the Lambda function currently? Have you tried simply increasing the memory available? https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/aws-lambda-supports-10gb-memory-6-vcpu-cores-lambda-functions/

Comment: yes, I have the maximum amount of memory. will update the post

Comment: Uhhh I'm skeptical that the file size is your problem. Your file is 400mb, your Lambda memory is 10gb... That means a 25x difference. In other words there are 9.6gb of RAM unaccounted for. That's a lot. This seems like a memory leak.

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver I will update the post with the full function code

Comment: What is `dictsToSend`? It only appears once and you don't do anything with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find anything in the code that should obviously be taking up a ton of memory (particularly: taking up memory across `for` iterations without releasing it in between iterations). You're closing the `StringIO` virtual file, which would be my prime suspect.

Given what you've said about memory profiling, here are *possible* solutions:

1. Change

```
response = s3.upload_fileobj(..., Fileobj=f.getValue())
```

to

```
response = s3.upload_fileobj(..., Fileobj=f)
```

This should avoid making a copy of the buffer (`f`) as a `String` in memory. This will take a single significant chunk out of memory usage - this may or may not be enough.

2. Refactor your code to *stream* your data - specifically, most of your collections are created, then iterated through once, then never used again. Instead, you could operate entry-by-entry across your data, doing *all* your transforms to each datapoint one-by-one. Unless you use [multi-part upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031463/can-you-upload-to-s3-using-a-stream-rather-than-a-local-file) you'll still need to hold all your data in memory before uploading it to S3, but this should still reduce memory usage.
3. (This is a bit of a nuclear option) at the end of your main loop, set your variables to `None` and [trigger garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python).

I would prefer 1 and/or 2 to 3. If 3 does work, I would be suspicious that something else is going wrong.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I will definitely try these

Comment: (great name btw), the smart_open route did work for me, im only using about 5 gigs of memory as opposed to blowing up at 10. the 400mb file becomes 1.5 Gb in size after transforming it so I guess that is just the way it is