# How do I upload to S3 if I'm already in a Conduit?

Tags: haskell, amazon-s3

In Haskell, I'm processing some data via conduits. During that processing, I want to conditionally store that data in S3. Are there any S3 libraries that will allow me to do this? Effectively, what I want to do is "tee" the pipeline created by the conduit and put the data it contains on S3 while continuing to process it.

I've found the aws library (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aws), but the functions like `multipartUpload` take a `Source` as an argument. Given that I'm already inside the conduit, this doesn't seem like something I can use.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a package—[amazonka-s3-streaming](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/amazonka-s3-streaming)—that exposes a multi-part upload to S3 as a conduit [Sink](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.3/conduit-1.2.11/Data-Conduit.html#t:Sink).

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but merely a hint. [`amazonka`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/amazonka-1.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-AWS.html) seems to expose [`RequestBody`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/amazonka-core-1.0.1/docs/Network-AWS-Data-Body.html#t:RqBody) of requests from `http-client`. So in theory it's possible to pipe data there from conduits. Yet seems that you have to know digest of the data beforehand.

So does tell [Can I stream a file upload to S3 without a content-length header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653146/can-i-stream-a-file-upload-to-s3-without-a-content-length-header) too.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question. As for amazonka, I believe I saw that a while ago, but it relies on lens. It (IIRC) is a really large dependency (as in, it added many minutes to compilation), so I disregarded it.