# Compressing data and upload it to S3 without keeping the full content in the memory

Tags: java, file-upload, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to compress data which is created dynamically using GZIP stream and upload it to S3 while I expect the data to be ±1Giga per compressed file.

Since the file size is big and I'm going to handle multiple files in parallel, I can't hold the entire data on memory and I wish to stream data to S3 as soon as possible.

Moreover, I can't know the exact size of the compress data. Reading this question "[Can I stream a file upload to S3 without a content-length header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653146/can-i-stream-a-file-upload-to-s3-without-a-content-length-header)" But I can't figure out how to combine it with GZIPing.

I think I could have done that if I was able to create `GZIPOutputStream`, send data to it part by part while simultaneously read chunks of the compressed data (hopefully of 5Mb) and upload them to S3 using [Amazon S3: Multipart upload](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-multipart-upload/)

Is what I'm trying to do is possible? Or my only option is to Compress the data to local storage (my hard disk) and than upload the compressed file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't take no for an answer, so this is how I did it:

```
package roee.gavriel;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CompleteMultipartUploadRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.InitiateMultipartUploadRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.InitiateMultipartUploadResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PartETag;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.UploadPartRequest;

public class S3UploadStream extends OutputStream {

    private final static Integer PART_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024;

    private final AmazonS3 s3client;
    private final String bucket;
    private final String key;

    // The upload id given to the multiple parts upload by AWS.
    private final String uploadId;
    // A tag list. AWS give one for each part and expect then when the upload is finish.
    private final List<PartETag> partETags = new LinkedList<>();
    // A buffer to collect the data before sending it to AWS.
    private byte[] partData = new byte[PART_SIZE];
    // The index of the next free byte on the buffer.
    private int partDataIndex = 0;
    // Total number of parts that where uploaded.
    private int totalPartCountIndex = 0;
    private volatile Boolean closed = false;
    // Internal thread pool which will handle the actual part uploading.
    private final ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    public S3UploadStream(AmazonS3 s3client, String bucket, String key, int uploadThreadsCount) {
        this.s3client = s3client;
        this.bucket = bucket;
        this.key = key;
        InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(bucket, key);
        InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse = s3client.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);
        this.uploadId = initResponse.getUploadId();
        this.executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(uploadThreadsCount, uploadThreadsCount, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100));
    }


    @Override
    public synchronized void write(int b) throws IOException {
        if (closed) {
            throw new IOException("Trying to write to a closed S3UploadStream");
        }
        partData[partDataIndex++] = (byte)b;
        uploadPart(false);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (closed) {
            return;
        }
        closed = true;

        // Flush the current data in the buffer
        uploadPart(true);

        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //Nothing to do here...
        }

        // Close the multiple part upload
        CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest = 
                new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(bucket, key, uploadId, partETags);

        s3client.completeMultipartUpload(compRequest);

    }

    private synchronized void uploadPart(Boolean force) {

        if (!force && partDataIndex < PART_SIZE) {
            // the API requires that only the last part can be smaller than 5Mb
            return;
        }

        // Actually start the upload
        createUploadPartTask(partData, partDataIndex);

        // We are going to upload the current part, so start buffering data to new part
        partData = new byte[PART_SIZE];
        partDataIndex = 0;          
    }

    private synchronized void createUploadPartTask(byte[] partData, int partDataIndex) {
        // Create an Input stream of the data
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(partData, 0, partDataIndex);

        // Build the upload request
        UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
                .withBucketName(bucket)
                .withKey(key)
                .withUploadId(uploadId)
                .withPartNumber(++totalPartCountIndex)
                .withInputStream(stream)
                .withPartSize(partDataIndex);

        // Upload part and add response to our tag list.
        // Make the actual upload in a different thread
        executor.execute(() -> {
            PartETag partETag = s3client.uploadPart(uploadRequest).getPartETag();
            synchronized (partETags) {
                partETags.add(partETag);
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

And here is a small snippest of code that use it to write many guid to S3 GZIP file:

```
int writeThreads = 3;
int genThreads = 10;
int guidPerThread = 200_000;
try (S3UploadStream uploadStream = new S3UploadStream(s3client, "<YourBucket>", "<YourKey>.gz", writeThreads)) {
    try (GZIPOutputStream stream = new GZIPOutputStream(uploadStream)) {
        Semaphore s = new Semaphore(0);
        for (int t = 0; t < genThreads; ++t) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < guidPerThread; ++i) {
                    try {
                        stream.write(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString().getBytes());
                        stream.write('\n');
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
                s.release();
            }).start();
        }
        s.acquire(genThreads);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. your answer was very helpful. I have a follow up question that I've been trying to tackle for some time now. Do you know if it's possible to continue zipping the file? I have this in a step function so if there is not enough time left in the lambda during zipping, then I close up and and circle back around to try and continue where it left off. I can't get it to work for the life of me. Do you have any ideas?