# Boto3 - get data from a generator and write to AWS S3 object?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have the following function to read data from a generator `source()`, which yield chunks of data (the length of the chunk is not fixed). And the data need to be written to a S3 object.

```
import boto3

async def write_s3(s3_key):
    session = boto3.Session()
    s3 = session.resource('s3')
    s3obj = s3.Object(BUCKET, s3_key)
    mpu = s3obj.initiate_multipart_upload()
    part = mpu.Part()

    async for chunk in source():
        # How to write all the chunks yield from source() to S3 (s3_key)?
        part.Upload(body=chunk)

    part_info = { .... }
    mpu_result = mpu.complete(MultipartUpload=part_info)
```

How to write all the chunks yielded from `source()` to an S3 object? The size of each chunk may vary.

Ref: [Stream large string to S3 using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52825430/stream-large-string-to-s3-using-boto3)

Comment: you can use boto3 for that. Please provide your code and describe what doesn't work for you

Comment: Yes, I need to use boto3. Updated the question with what I found.

Comment: so what is the problem? exceptions or smth?