# Setting size parameter in content-disposition header with Javascript

Tags: javascript, http, axios

#### The Problem

I've been trying to set the `size` parameter in the content-disposition header for quite some time.

```
function uploadFile(file) {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', file);

    axios.post('url/of/endpoint', data);
```

FormData does not send the size parameter by default and, to my knowledge, I can't see a way of setting it myself. Is there a way of doing this with Axios? Do I need to go more lower level and build my own headers?

#### The Context

My primary objective is to pipe a file input stream via a Java endpoint to S3. But without the file size, all of the data gets loaded into memory and has a high chance of causing an OOM exception. This specific problem [has been asked here as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653146/can-i-stream-a-file-upload-to-s3-without-a-content-length-header). Is writing my own byte buffer the only way? Should I just stop being lazy and do that? Seems like an overly-complex solution...

Is there a reason as to why the file size isn't normally included in FormData? I've tried using Content-Length, but that includes the content-disposition header and leads to a mismatched byte count.

Comment: What would you do with `size` or `content-length`?

Comment: @KoshVery Give it to the Amazon SDK so it can break down the file for multipart? Again, [the context has been asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653146/can-i-stream-a-file-upload-to-s3-without-a-content-length-header).

Comment: Is it possible if storing in cloud dB instead of cloud file storage https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/5s6g3n/binaryblob_storage_alternative_in_aws/#ampf=undefined

Comment: Java or JavaScript?

Comment: @Barmar original question is for Javascript, the context involves Java

Answer (score 1):

Right, so after going around the office... then to my friends... I come to the conclusion that this is a Java shortcoming. Well, not the original question, but the fact that a multipart upload requires the total file size. So, the implementation I'm currently going with, which makes me feel super dirty, is adding a FormData item `size` on the client side.

```
function uploadFile(file) {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('size', file.size.toString());
    data.append('file', file);

    axios.post('url/of/endpoint', data);
```

And then updating the backend to pass that size to the S3 SDK... ... oof.