# How to set a content length for AWS S3 HTTP upload with presigned url for a file that is gz-compressed in std::fstream?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, stream

I have to upload a file with a presigned URL that S3 creates for me. To save up some space and time I am using a stream that compresses the file into .gz-format. So the S3 just receives the gz-file.

I use the [AWS S3 CPP SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp). The `AWS::HttpClient` for the HTTP request and `boost` for the compression.

I am asking myself how can I set the content length for the HTTP request correctly? On one hand it is a stream, on the other hand the stream will be compressed (gz) which makes it not easier. I have no idea how to do this, sadly.

I tried to get the length with `seekg()` and `tellg()` but I couldn't solve my problem.

```
auto&& f = std::fstream{ filepath.string(), std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary };

auto in = std::make_shared<boost::iostreams::filtering_stream<boost::iostreams::bidirectional>>();
in->push(boost::iostreams::combine(boost::iostreams::gzip_compressor(), boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor()));
in->push(f);

req->AddContentBody(in);
//req->SetContentLength(); <-- How?
req->SetContentType("application/octet-stream");

auto res = MyHttpClient->MakeRequest(req);  //upload stream
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Content-Length` must be the actual number of bytes being sent. If you are compressing data dynamically while sending it then obviously you can't know the final compressed size up front to set a `Content-Length` correctly. Fortunately, you don't have to, as S3 has a [multipart upload API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html) that supports streaming uploads. See [Can I stream a file upload to S3 without a content-length header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653146/).