# Write Zip file to AWS as a stream

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

Using C#, I would like to create a zip file in AWS S3,  add file entries to it, then close the stream.  System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive can be created from a System.IO.Stream. Is it possible to get a writeable stream into an S3 bucket? I am using the .NET SDK FOR S3.

Comment: So, the question really has nothing to do with Zip files.  It's "can I write a stream into an S3 bucket"?  If you can't directly, I'm guessing you can write a `byte[]` into one.  If so, you can use a `MemoryStream`

Answer (score 1):

An object uploaded to S3 must have a known size when the request is made. Since the size of the zip file won't be known till the stream is closed you can't do what you are asking about. You would have to create the zip file locally then upload it to S3.

The closest you could get to what you are asking for is using S3's multi part upload. I would use a MemoryStream as the underlying stream for the ZipArchive and each time you add a file to the zip archive check to see if the MemoryStream is larger than 5 megabytes. If it is take the byte buffer from the MemoryStream and upload a new part to S3. Then clear the MemoryStream and continue adding files to the zip archive.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to take a look at [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653146/can-i-stream-a-file-upload-to-s3-without-a-content-length-header) for an existing discussion around this.

This [doc page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtility_Upload_1.htm) seems to suggest that there is an Upload method can take a stream (with S3 taking care of re-assembling the multi-part upload). Although this is for version 1 so might not be available in version 3.