# Is it possible to upload a file to S3 without reading or duplicating it?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fs

I'm trying to upload a file to S3 but the file size is too large and we need to do it very frequently . So I was looking for if there is any option to upload a file to S3 using nodejs , without reading the content of the file wholly.
The below code was working fine , but it was reading the file each time I want to upload .

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: process.env.ACCESS_SECRET,
  accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.REGION,
});
const BUCKET = process.env.BUCKET;
const s3 = new aws.S3();
const fileName = "logs.txt";

const uploadFile = () => {
  fs.readFile(fileName, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const params = {
      Bucket: BUCKET, // pass your bucket name
      Key: fileName, // file will be saved as testBucket/contacts.csv
      Body: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2),
    };
    s3.upload(params, function (s3Err, data) {
      if (s3Err) throw s3Err;
      console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`);
    });
  });
};

uploadFile();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multipart upload:

AWS article:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-multipart-upload/

SO Question about the same for python: [Can I stream a file upload to S3 without a content-length header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653146/can-i-stream-a-file-upload-to-s3-without-a-content-length-header)

JS API reference manual: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html

The basic example is:

```
var upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
  params: {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Body: stream}
});
```

so you have to provide a stream as an input.

```
const readableStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
```

JS api documented here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fscreatereadstreampath-options

Of course, you can process the data while reading it and then pass it to the S3 API, you just have to implement the Stream API.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of streams.

First create a readStream of the file you want to upload. You then can pipe it to aws s3 by passing it as Body.

```js
import { createReadStream } from 'fs';

const inputStream = createReadStream('sample.txt');

s3
  .upload({ Key: fileName, Body: inputStream, Bucket: BUCKET })
  .promise()
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```